# Angularjs undefined function Error: ng:areq Bad Argument

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am taking baby steps learning angularjs from video tutorial and as i reached the controllers section i had this error:

> Argument 'SimpleController' is not a function, got undefined

although i followed the steps carefully.Please bare in mind that this is all i know about angularjs so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">
    <head></head>

    <body>
        <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" id=""> {{ name }}

            <br>

            <h3>Looping with the ng-repeat Directive</h3>

            <ul>
                <li data-ng-repeat="cutomer in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city'">{{ cutomer.name | uppercase }} - {{ cutomer.city | lowercase }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function SimpleController($scope) {
                $scope.customers = [
                    {name:'Yasser Moussa',city:'Alexandria'},
                    {name:'Ahmed Salah',city:'Al Riyadh'},
                    {name:'Khaled Medhat',city:'Alexandria'},
                    {name:'Ali Dawood',city:'Cairo'}
                ];
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Your code seems works well](https://jsfiddle.net/do4oLgkd/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a module, called "app"
2. Assign the control to that module using 
   `angular.module("app", []).controller("SimpleController, function() {})`
3. Declare the module in your html using `data-ng-app="app"`

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QaN3YW8xAeOJfGCz55hz)

Comment: Thanks man it seem to work just i wanted to know why the code from the video tutorial didn't work for me was it like outdated syntax or something like that

Comment: It's just incomplete. Angular requires at least 1 module to be declared with a name that is used in your ng-app directive. It also requires the controller be part of that module.

I included the plunker just to reinforce these concepts. If you open the plunker, and remove the "app" from data-ng-app="app", you will see why it is required.